# Dual monitors resolution reset on each restart

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, resolution

Environment:

- **OS:** Xubuntu 13.04
- **Linux kernel:** 3.8.0-35
- **Nvidia driver version:** 313.30
- **GPU Name:** GeForce GT 630
- **Monitors:**

  - **Dell U2312HM**. Connected to DVI port of video card (without any adapter).
  - **LG W1943SS**. Connected to VGA port of video card (without any adapter).

After each PC reboot the settings resets to the following (screenshot of Dell display):

[image: After reboot]

LG display overlaps the Dell display, but before reboot there was the following configuration:

[image: What I set]

I tried to save X configuration to file but nothing changed, the same situation after reboot...
I tried to change VGA and DVI cables but it doesn't help.

I have generated Nvidia bug report file that contains at least Xorg.log and Xorg.conf: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0a0e5a8a5815d7a64d92

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened `Settings Manager -> Display` and configured displays using it. After reboot there was no settings reset.

[[SOLVED] Dual monitors resolution reset on each restart - NVIDIA Developer Forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/676106/linux/dual-monitors-resolution-reset-on-each-restart)